# Dragging an element inside a div but the element flashes when dragged

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, draggable

I'm trying to drag an element around inside another div but it is constantly flashing when being dragged around. I recreated the problem with this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-cache-l3yos

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="board" @mousemove="dragOver">
      <div
        class="draggableItem"
        @mousedown="dragStart"
        @mouseup="dragStop"
        :style="{top: this.top + 'px', left: this.left + 'px'}"
      >This should be draggable</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      isDragging: false,
      top: 50,
      left: 50
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dragOver: function(e) {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        this.left = e.offsetX;
        this.top = e.offsetY;
      }
    },
    dragStart: function(e) {
      this.isDragging = true;
    },
    dragStop: function(e) {
      this.isDragging = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the position as an offset from start position, and then update it based on the movement. This will allow to draw by any part. You can (and should IMHO) attach and remove the event handlers dynamically.

Here is what that might look like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="board">
      <div
        class="draggableItem"
        @mousedown="dragStart"
        :style="{top: this.top + 'px', left: this.left + 'px'}"
      >This should be draggable</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      isDragging: false,
      top: 50,
      left: 50,
      startTop: 0,
      startLeft: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dragOver: function(e) {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        this.top = e.clientY - this.startTop;
        this.left = e.clientX - this.startLeft;
      }
    },
    dragStart: function(e) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.dragOver)
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.dragStop)
      this.isDragging = true;
      this.startTop = e.clientY - this.top;
      this.startLeft = e.clientX - this.left;
    },
    dragStop: function(e) {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.dragOver)
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.dragStop)
      this.isDragging = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you maybe know how I can prevent the element from reszining if you drag completely to the right? I you drag to the left the element doesn't resize but when dragging to the right it does.

Comment: that's a css issue, you may need to change the display property